# Getting time difference per unique row items using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please show me how to use pandas to get time difference per unique rows in the following data (df):

```
Round   Order   Date
1   1   2011.02.04 00:20:21
1   2   2011.02.04 00:25:11
1   3   2011.02.04 00:35:10
1   4   2011.02.04 00:47:10
2   1   2011.02.04 00:21:21
2   2   2011.02.04 00:31:11
2   3   2011.02.04 00:41:10
```

Because of the sequential order i column 'Order', the time difference will be the date value in row 4 minus the date value in row 1. So I want to arrive at this table (time_df):

```
Round   TimeDiff
1   26.39
2   19.39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with difference `min` and `max`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')   
print df
   Round  Order                Date
0      1      1 2011-02-04 00:20:21
1      1      2 2011-02-04 00:25:11
2      1      3 2011-02-04 00:35:10
3      1      4 2011-02-04 00:47:10
4      2      1 2011-02-04 00:21:21
5      2      2 2011-02-04 00:31:11
6      2      3 2011-02-04 00:41:10

print df.groupby('Round')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
Round
1   00:26:49
2   00:19:49
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @jezrael for helping me out. Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
In [324]: df
Out[324]:
   Round  Order                Date
0      1      1 2011-02-04 00:20:21
1      1      2 2011-02-04 00:25:11
2      1      3 2011-02-04 00:35:10
3      1      4 2011-02-04 00:47:10
4      2      1 2011-02-04 00:21:21
5      2      2 2011-02-04 00:31:11
6      2      3 2011-02-04 00:41:10

In [325]: grp = df.groupby('Round')

In [327]: grp.Date.max()-grp.Date.min()
Out[327]:
Round
1   00:26:49
2   00:19:49
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and time. I have learnt from your solution too.